# Dates and workflows

Tags: workflow-activity

I've set up a form for my employees to request vacation. Out the box list and form. Whenever they entered the start date I always get the request with one day delay.

For Example:
 Joe request off starting 12/1/2012

When I get the request (using workflow email) the request says 11/30/2012.

Can anyone help? I'm think it might have to do with time zone but i don't know.

Comment: Do you have the date as notify within 30 days, instead of one month? How is your workflow set up? Can you post the logic?